# SonarQube C# Analysis Fails to 'Not a Valid Line Offset for Pointer'

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube

I have projects that I've been analysing with SonarQube succesfully for a while, but now I'm having some errors. The exact error is:

```
12:26:01.413 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 74 is not a valid line offset for pointer. File [blaablaablaa...] has 70 character(s) at line 118
    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.checkValid(DefaultInputFile.java:252)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newPointer(DefaultInputFile.java:186)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRange(DefaultInputFile.java:202)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor$SarifParserCallbackImplementation.onIssue(AbstractSensor.java:160)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleResultFileElement(SarifParser10.java:130)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleLocationsElement(SarifParser10.java:102)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleIssue(SarifParser10.java:73)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleIssues(SarifParser10.java:62)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.accept(SarifParser10.java:54)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.accept(SarifParser10.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.importRoslynReport(CSharpSensor.java:188)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.executeInternal(CSharpSensor.java:123)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.execute(CSharpSensor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:175)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:262)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:257)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:255)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
12:26:01.419 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
12:26:01.420 DEBUG: Execution stop
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

I have updated the C# analyzer to the latest (**5.10.1 (build 1411) installed**). At least the update center doesn't provide a newer?

I also updated the scanner to **sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.3.2.573**

I'm using **SQ 6.3.1.21392**

There are quite a few similar posts here in SO, but all of them are pretty old and they suggest that it's either a known bug in the analyzer or an encoding issue. I've tried to change the problem file encoding to plain UTF-8, but that doesn't resolve the issue. Notepad++ shows the encoding is UTF-8-BOM. I've also used the bomremover, but that doesn't change the error at all.

Any suggestions what to try except to exclude all the problem files from the analyse?

**EDIT**
The encoding of the file is UTF-8-BOM, but it makes no difference to convert it to plain UTF-8.

[image: File encoding of the problem file]

I used Notepad++ convert to UTF-8 and re-run the analysis. Same error as a result and here's a screenshot of the new encoding:

[image: converted file encoding]

Comment: How many columns do you have at line 118? SonarQube "see" 70 but it seems that Roslyn "see" at least 74.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam I have 70 columns in that line.

Comment: Roslyn report is somehow wrong. The best chance to find the root cause would be that you: 1) open an issue on [sonar-csharp](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues) 2) share the offending C# file unmodified (just to check the encoding) 3) share the Roslyn report (should be located at <your Project>\bin\Debug\<your project>.exe.RoslynCA.json If you can't share some information publicly, just mention it on the issue and we'll give you a private address you can send the information to.

Comment: Our project is on it's way to Github, so I'll let you know the URL once we are there so everyone can see there. I updated the original question with information of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by re-cloning the repo and running the analysis again. The root cause of the problem remains unknown.

If you are having the same issue, try to re-create the file again by either cloning the repo to different location or by copy-paste the file contents inside newly created file.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue was caused for bad LF format, using MAC (CR) LF on windows.