# Project’s Sonarqube scan issue in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a CI pipeline in Azure DevOps for .net core app.  Below is the task list in the job.

1] Prepare Analysis Configuration (5.0.0) 2] .NET Core (2.187.0) to    restore, build, publish and test 3] Run Code Analysis (5.0.0)

Build failing at the “Run Code Analysis” step. Error details below.

```
##[error]java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Start pointer [line=40, lineOffset=49] should be before end pointer [line=40, lineOffset=49]
```

Comment: End up with same error even after changing the .cs file encoding from “UTF-8 BOM” to “UTF-8”. Encoding changed in VS Code and pushed to the repo.

Comment: Same error even after .gitatributes added to Azure repo, with "*  text=auto  encoding=UTF-8, *.cs  eol=lf diff=csharp  encoding=UTF-8 "

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities to fix the illegal attribute exception

Change your **encoding** method into

1. UTF-8
2. UTF-8 with BOM
3. and others like (UTF-16 LE, UTF-16 LE with BOM, UTF-16 BE, UTF-16 BE with BOM, Western (Windows 1252)) as per your usage

Try to re-create the file again by either **cloning** the repo to different location or by copy-paste the file contents inside newly created file.

Try to use the Recent **Sonarqube** version 9.1

Refer here [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997878/sonarqube-c-sharp-analysis-fails-to-not-a-valid-line-offset-for-pointer) & [Link 2](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/102-is-not-a-valid-line-offset-for-pointer/24342)